# Need help in installation of mongodb with codeigniter

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I have never used mongo db with codeigniter any one can guide me step by step for complete installation and usage.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting started with Mongodb and CodeIgniter [Link](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-php-codeigniter-mongodb-paas)